# where to put "that" in the sentence

Tags: adverbs, subordinate-clauses

Should *that* be placed here:

> On 12/10 the physician notes indicated **that** on evaluation the patient had a poor oral intake and her pain was not well controlled on Tylenol alone.

or here:

> On 12/10 the physician notes indicated [no pronouns] on evaluation that the patient had a poor oral intake and her pain was not well controlled on Tylenol alone.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had questions about how things work around here, take some of your time to visit [the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: @MARamezani Nice welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

*That* in this sentence is not, as you appear to think, a relative pronoun but a *subordinating conjunction* (in traditional terminology) or subordinator (in modern terminology). It 'marks' the following clause as subordinate: in this case the Direct Object of the verb *indicate*.

So this is  really more a question of where the phrase *on evaluation* is placed, before or after the subordinator *that*.

That phrase is a time reference modifying the clause it is placed in.

If it is placed **before** the *that*, it belongs to the main clause and modifies that, telling the reader when the notes 'indicated' the patient's symptoms. That is absurd: the notes 'indicate' the patient's symptoms whenever they are read, not just at the time when the patient was evaluated.

The phrase therefore belongs **after** the *that*, so that it is belongs to the subordinate clause and tells the reader *when* the patient had these symptoms and complaints.